# Show that $a * \lambda(f \ge a) \le \int_{\Omega} f(x) d\lambda(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \lambda)$ be a measure space, $a \ge 0$ a constant and $f: \Omega \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function. Show that
>
> $a * \lambda(f \ge a) \le \int_{\Omega} f(x) d\lambda(x)$.

I thought it might be easier to prove this thing while assuming that $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure first, and I would like to know whether my proof is correct or not.

Let $\Omega = \Bbb R$ and $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue-measure.

Since $f$ is measurable and non-negative, we know that there is a sequence of increasing simple functions $f_k$ with $f_k \uparrow f$ such that

$\int_{\Omega} f d\lambda = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_k$.

Furthermore, we are allowed to assume that a $\le \sup(f)$, because for $a > \sup(f)$, the set $(f \ge a)$ would be empty (since there can't be no such $x \in \Omega)$ and the inequality would be true trivially. We write:

$a * \lambda(f \ge a) = a * c$ for some constant $c \in \Bbb R_+$, which is just the length of the interval of $(f \ge a)$. We define

$g := a * c$,

which is just the volumn of the rectangle spanned by $a$ and $c$. Now, since $a \le \sup(f)$, we know that there must be a $k_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $g \le f_k$ for every $k \ge k_0$, and since $f_k \uparrow f$, we get that $g \le f$, and hence

$g = \int_{(f \ge a)} a * x$ $d\lambda(x) \le \int_{\Omega} f(x)$ $d\lambda(x)$.

Comment: You say that $\lambda(f \ge a)$ is the length of the interval of $(f \ge a)$. However, $(f \ge a)$ is not necessarily an interval. So what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: > which is just the length of the interval of $(f \ge a)$
Why should that be an interval? In general that's not true. Take $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$, then there are countable many intervals… > Now, since $a \le \sup(f)$ , we know that there must be a $k_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $g \le f_k$
That's also not true if $a=\sup(f)$

So your proof have a bunch of lacks…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much too complicated…

$$\int_{\Omega} f d\lambda = \int_{\{f<a\}} f d\lambda + \int_{\{f\ge a\}} f d\lambda \ge 0 + \int_{\{f\ge a\}} a d\lambda = a\lambda\left(\{f\ge a\}\right)$$

Comment: Does the proof for arbitrary measures work similar? :-)

Comment: Do you see any dependency of the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Well, yes, I would say that it's hard to use the same argument for arbitrary measures, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I mean, you used the fact that the Lebesgue-measure gives out the length of an interval defined on the real numbers. That is very specific. I don't think that other measures work the same way.

Comment: > I mean, you used the fact that the Lebesgue-measure gives out the length of an interval defined on the real numbers.

I didn't… I just used properties of measures…

Comment: Which properties might that be? :-)

Comment: Oh, I see, I guess you used the identity $\lambda(A) = \int_{\Omega} X_A d\lambda$ for the last equation?

Comment: And since you integrate over $\{f \ge a\}$, the indicator function is always identical with $1$.

Comment: Yes I used that identity but keep in mind that $\lambda(A) = \int_{\Omega} X_A d\lambda = \int_A 1 d\lambda$  holds so ofc $\int_{\{f\ge a\}} a d\lambda = a \int_{\{f\ge a\}}1 d\lambda = a \int_\Omega \chi_{\{f\ge a\}} d\lambda = a\lambda\left(\{f\ge a\}\right)$